# Postgresql - convert DATE into a specific DATE format

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert the dates in my date column from:

`yyyy-mm-dd`

to

`Month dd, yyyy`

So far i've tried the below:

```
SELECT To_char(sq2.date_column, Month DD, YYYY)
```

but get the below error, despite my pattern [aligning to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "DD"
```

I noticed in the documentation that `To_char` isn't explicitly referenced for date conversion (only time). Also, i'm not necessarily trying to alter the DATE type to VARCHAR. I would be happy to keep the data in the date_column as DATE type and just change the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You were damn close. Just missed the `'` at the second parameter.

`SELECT To_char('2018-01-20'::date, 'Month DD, YYYY')`

Using your table column:

`SELECT To_char(sq2.date_column, 'Month DD, YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use single code before month and end of the YYYY.
you can use fallowing query for your required result
SELECT To_char(sq2.date_column, 'Month DD, YYYY')